# Python Flask REST API path 404

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, plesk

I am currently undertaking to develop a simple REST API in Python. When I access the URL through my browser, I get `snake.app-host.com/login` a 405 error, which is expected in this context.
However, when I use Postman, I encounter a 404 error. can you help me ?

Postman Request to

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 3970752f-9666-4f02-92a1-6fda1b7bc77b
Host: snake.app-host.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 58
 
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "password"
}
```

Error return 404 error page :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2023 06:57:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: br
 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at snake.app-host.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

user need to access the /login route with body username/password for a return JWT Token

Simple REST Api based on python / flask

```py
import sys
import os
import logging
import jwt
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
conf_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'confs')
sys.path.append(conf_dir)
mdl_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'models')
sys.path.append(mdl_dir)

from confapp import APP_HOST,APP_IP, APP_PORT, APP_NAME, APP_NAMESPACE, APP_SALT, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# API Endpoints

# start
@app.route('/')
def helloWorld():
    return '''<html><h1>Hello CORS!</h1></html>'''
# .start

# login
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    # Obtenir les informations d'identification de l'utilisateur depuis la requête
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')

    # Vérifier les informations d'identification de l'utilisateur (par exemple, dans une base de données)
    # Si les informations sont valides, générer un token JWT
    if username == 'admin' and password == 'password':
        payload = {'username': username}
        token = jwt.encode(payload, APP_SALT, algorithm='HS256')
        return jsonify({'token': token.decode('utf-8')})

    # Si les informations d'identification ne sont pas valides, retourner une réponse d'erreur
    return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}), 401

# .login

# error
@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request. %s', e)
    return "An internal error occurred", 500
# .error

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host=APP_IP, port=APP_PORT)
```

Plesk Rules

```bash
PassengerEnabled On

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wsgi.py/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/httpdocs/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

# CORS Policies
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</IfModule>

# WSGI
WSGIDaemonProcess venv_snakesx processes=2 threads=2  python-path=/var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/httpdocs/confs:/var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/httpdocs/models python-home=/var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/.pyenv/
WSGIProcessGroup venv_snakesx
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGITrustedProxyHeaders X-Forwarded-Host X-Forwarded-Port X-Forwarded-For
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/snake.app-host.com/httpdocs/wsgi.py process-group=venv_snakesx
```

Plesk Obsidian 18.0.5

Python 3.10 - Flask

Apache - WSGI

Comment: Does the "helloworld" route work from Postman?

Comment: no it doesn't work either :/